# How to perform image thresholding and normalization in OpenCV?

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have a 16 bit image that I want to convert to a 8 bit image. However I want to do some filtering before that. All values that are below some value (say P1) should become 0. And all values above a different value (say P2) should become 255. All values in between those values should be scaled according to their distance to P1 and P2.

The following code does this:

```
def transform(value):
    if value < P1:
        value = 0
    elif value > P2:
        value = 255
    else:
        value = (value - P1) * (255.0 / (P2 - P1))
    return value
```

And then using the original 16 bit image as input:

```
newImage= [[transform(value) for value in row] for row in originalImage]
```

However this is incredibly slow... I have tried to do the same using `cv2.convertScaleAbs`, which is fast, but doesn't entirely do what I want. Especially the 'Abs' part in this function is making it impossible for me to use.

Are there different functions I can use to get the thing I want in a faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that does use `cv2.convertScaleAbs`

First scale the original image to be interperted as int32:

```
originalImage = numpy.array(originalImage, dtype=np.int32)
```

Then subtract the P1 value, making all values that are smaller than P1 negative:

```
newImage = np.array(originalImage - P1)
```

Then clip the negative values to 0:

```
newImage = newImage.clip(min=0)
```

Lastly use `convertScaleAbs` with the correct alpha:

```
alpha = 255.0 / (P2 - P1)
newImage= cv2.convertScaleAbs(newImage, alpha=alpha)
```